# Is it legal for me to post previous exams I have taken in University

Tags: copyright, exams, legal-issues, publishability

I want to create a database of notes and previous exams for classes at my university, however, I am not sure if this is legal. I just want to know if this is OK or would I get a cease and desist or something similar from my university? And does posting the exams with/without answers make a difference?

Edit: Sincerely I didn't expect such quick responses and so many of them so thank you guys and thanks to all that may answer in advance. But also, I think I need to clarify some things to get a more concrete answer. First, I want to make clear that I will not charge anything for this website or access to it, second of all, I would change all the numbers of the questions, from say 2 + 2 to 7 + 5, and I don't think mathematics in any way shape or form can be copyrighted, of course exact wording and scenarios like Alice went can, but not something like prove the sum from 1 to n is (n(n+1))/2 or if it indeed is please point me to a US copyright law that says that. Per my understanding, "known, rational facts" cannot be copyrighted, since then you wouldn't even be able to do math to begin with because you'd be using way too many formulas written for other people.

Comment: Did you write the exams? Do you own the copyright to them?

Comment: "I just want to know if this is OK or would I get a cease and desist or something similar from my university?" Asking whether this is OK or you would "get a cease and desist from your university" is rather like asking whether it is OK to cheat on exams or whether you will end up in jail if you cheat. In other words, the space between the two extreme options is rather large.

Comment: you might get a better legal answer from the legal forum.

Comment: Do you mean an own database or "contributing" them to Course Hero?

Comment: Don't waste your time, do some sport, travel or socialize rather being busy with this stuff. Let others do some fair amount of studying.

Comment: If the faculty who composed the exam, and/or the relevant departments, did not _already_ put the stuff on the internet, that might be an indicator that they don't want it to be "public". Or, it could be that they simply didn't want to take the time. _OR_ maybe they're trying to keep things secret. I'd think you should (politely) directly ask them ... (E.g., I put all my course stuff on-line, so there'd not be much reason for a student to separately archive it...)

Comment: @JonCuster Keep in mind that in British English, "writing an exam" refers to what in AmE is referred to as "taking an exam".

Comment: @Acccumulation - good point - so what is used to refer to authoring the exam? Always fun to learn these things...

Comment: Are these relatively unimaginative questions like "*Given $f(x)= \sin x$, find $\frac{df}{dx}$.*"?

Comment: Surely the exams at your university are more complex than just a single question like „prove the sum from 1 to n is (n(n+1))/2“, no? Just because a small excerpt would not be protected by copyright does not mean an entire work is not protected by Copyright, nor that chopping it up but keeping all the pieces avoids Copyright.

Answer (score 27):

"Legal" is a local question. Probably civic, not criminal, law. But it isn't appropriate. The questions were probably created by someone else and if there is any creative element in them, then they are likely covered by copyright, even if not explicitly stated. That could be a legal issue. Appropriateness, however, is a different, possibly more important, issue.

But, if they can be found, you are also subverting the educational process if you make cheating possible on reused questions. While professors probably should't reuse exam questions, the reality is that they do. Shortcuts taken for grades are seldom an educational/learning benefit for those who take them.

You could, of course, ask your professors for their position on this. They might agree or not. But it would be respectful to do so.

Comment: "subverting the educational process" Not necessarily. In Germany, it is common that the [AStA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AStA) maintains a collection of old exams, often including the solutions. Everyone is aware of this and thus professors don't reuse exams. (To be honest, if an exam is well-designed, studying it to a point where you can answer the questions should result in sufficient mastery of the material to be allowed to pass. Working through old exams taught me almost as much as visiting the lectures.)

Comment: +1 for suggesting asking the instructors who composed the exams. (And if one is reluctant to hear the composers' wishes, that in itself is probably the answer.)

Comment: downvoting as both off topic and speculation.

Comment: @Roland, I agree that in a place with such a system it would be different and instructors would work differently. But that isn't the question at hand here.

Comment: “If you make cheating possible on reused questions”: sorry, correctly answering an exam question because it was reused absolutely does not count as “cheating”. And as for “subverting the educational process”, if anyone can be said to be subverting the educational process it is the professors who reuse exam questions. To put it differently, an educational process that depends on a large group of people collectively keeping a shared secret despite never agreeing to keep it secret or having any incentive to, frankly deserves to be subverted.

Comment: Is it really inappropriate? Perhaps I'm being naive. I come from the UK, and for every exam I've ever taken the *only* preparation ever recommended in the run-up to an exam is practicing past papers. Exam boards make them available online, and websites offering worked solutions to *every past paper ever written* are common. People make careers out of it, and students would be substantially worse off if this (copyright-violating, perhaps) practice were not common. Is that outweighed by the convenience for an exam setter?

Comment: I feel pretty strongly that it is appropriate to share old exams.  At large universities, fraternities and sororities keep records of old exams to benefit other members in the future who take those classes.  Often questions are reused.  I went to a large University where the print shop kept copies of old exams and made them available to all students, and I feel that went a long way to the meritocratization of grades.  Especially in large survey classes.

Comment: Assuming the education is worth anything cheating would be detrimental. Sure you pass a class but in the next class you're even more lost and probability is increasingly not in your favor since eventually exam questions will change.

Comment: @preferred_anon practicing past exams develops students' pattern matching skills, which is recognised as a shallow learning technique and hence discouraged.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Recognised by who? I've never seen an institution that simultaneously uses written exams and does not encourage practising from past papers. If your past papers only test pattern matching, they aren't worth writing.

Comment: You can boost up your exam score by practising on past papers, but it will have a short-term effect and would not achieve long-term goals. Next term in the next course that relies on this skills you will struggle. This is widely understood in educational literature and practice. Students are encouraged to practise on past exams on top of systematic learning in class and revision, not as a substitution of them.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: That will depend a lot on the type of question in the exam. Certainly in many topics I've studied, practising questions from past papers would have been (and indeed was) excellent preparation for future courses - I guess because the papers were well designed to be a good test of the skills that would be required, and hence mere "pattern matching" would not get you very far.

Comment: @preferred_anon I was trained in the UK system and I teach at a UK university and I agree with Dmitry S. here. As for "websites offering worked solutions to every past paper ever written are common", I don't see this as a desirable feature. Moreover, re "if your past papers only test pattern matching, they aren't worth writing" - please try working in UKHE to satisfy the demands of the politicians, the TEF, the KEF and the league tables before presuming to judge those who have to set exams in this system

Comment: @YemonChoi I have the utmost respect for people setting exams in UK universities, and at universities in general. I am not passing judgement on them - I just have more faith in the quality of their exams than you seem to. You say that available worked solutions are not a desirable feature. Do you have any justification for this? I have never set an exam, but I've *sat* them. Do you deny that studying worked solutions helps students to learn? (please do not mix this up with "reading solutions instead of trying", which is obviously not a good way to learn)

Comment: I have asked some professors however not everyone has the time to meet and talk about if they want their exams on a website. That said, I don't get 100s on every exam, even if I did it would be blatantly obvious they copied a proof word by word and more importantly how would someone have the ability to memorize all these questions and answers worst part is most exams have A and B versions and of course I only have one copy so I don't get how would that encourage cheating and if it did how is a website like chegg still up?

Answer (score 23):

In all jurisdictions I know, professors (or in some cases their employers) retain copyrights over their exams, so unless the copyright holder themselves post the exams and you link to their site, it is illegal for you to repost unless you have permission.

The same holds for lecture notes or any other material, including third party material that may have been used by instructors (*v.g.* images, slides, audio contents etc.), especially as such material may be updated to remove obsolete material or correct errors.

Comment: In countries where universities are publicly owned, and where works created by the government are not protected by copyright, this doesn't seem like it should be a given.

Comment: @kaya3 Imagine trying to write a research paper at a university where you didn't have copyright protection. The instant you send a draft to a colleague, a publisher, etc, you would lose all control over it and they could just take your work, remove your name, and publish it without your permission.

Comment: @anjama No, that would be plagiarism by the colleague.  Plagiarism and copyright are two different issues.

Comment: @kaya3 I work at a publicly funded university and I still own copyrights to all my exams and course notes.  Students cannot reproduce or distribute said exams or course notes without my consent or in some cases the contents of the university (v.g. for final exams available to students via a university website.)

Comment: My point is: simply because the government is the source of university funding does not imply in any way that the government automatically owns the rights to my work, or that I forfeited copyrights to my work.  The university or government certainly do not own copyrights to my papers, which are creative works produced under employment: in fact when I publish something I transfer the copyright to the journal without government or university involvement.

Comment: When I started my post-graduate study in Australia, one of the documents I signed clearly laid out where ownership of intellectual property lies. This is quite different to industry where my employment contract specifically claims all related work I do in employment as the property of my emploter.

Comment: @anjama This already happens for US federal employees, e.g. those employed by NASA, National Institutes of Health, National Institute of Standards and Technology, Naval Research Lab, etc. Papers written solely by federal employees have copyright disclaimers. ([Example](https://doi.org/10.1083/jcb.202111077), see the very bottom)

Comment: @kaya3 Which country are you referring to? In the U.S., for example, works created by the federal government or its agencies are public domain, but that does not mean that works created by public universities funded by federal funds are automatically public domain. Besides, I believe most American public universities are state-funded anyway, and I believe the public domain rule doesn't apply to state governments anyway. In any case, universities are not considered government institutions at any level. However, your comment may be interesting if we're talking about a U.S. military academy.

Comment: @Brandin I didn't have any particular country in mind, rather I am not sure that it is definitely true in all countries that a lecturer working for a government-owned university (or the university itself) would necessarily retain copyright of exams they write within their employed role. Perhaps that is indeed the case in every country, it just doesn't seems that easy to say that it is; so I'm not saying it's wrong, just that it doesn't seem like a given.

Answer (score 9):

At my university, sharing course material without authorization is a fairly direct violation of our academic honesty policy.

Comment: Academic honesty policy? This sounds like it would apply to sharing an exam with other students who would be taking that exam. I would not expect it to apply to an exam taken in the past. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @kaya3 - any material given to a student as part of a course.  I suppose sanction options go down after a student graduates, but anything short of that, we'll find an appropriate sanction for.

Comment: poster didnt ask what the university thinks. its pretty clear from the question the poster doesnt care what the uni thinks. i certainly dont care what a university thinks. poster is asking about legality.

Comment: legal system consists of many layers. The relations between a student and a University are covered by the educational agreement (contract), which stipulates the honesty code.

Comment: @user156207, I would put this in the "something similar from my university" category, which was asked for.  In other words, replace "Cease and Desist" with "finding of academic dishonesty", which can be a ton more significant to students in certain situations (like those with a previous dishonesty record can get a suspension or permanent separation -- as opposed to taking stuff down in response to a take-down order).

Comment: It violates your academic honesty policy to share resources to help learning the material?!

Comment: @user156207  "What the Uni thinks" is certainly a factor towards legality - if they have policies that specifically allow this, then it is highly unlikely that any jurisdiction will find it to be illegal.  On the other hand, a clear policy against sharing, may well draw a "line in the sand" that does make it illegal.

Comment: @preferred_anon sharing course materials with people not on the course may violate copyright held by lecturers or University

Comment: @MikeB then the answer should be produced through that perspective. Violating university policy or academic integrity in no way equals illegal. i see no evidence the poster cares one bit what the uni thinks. all i see on this thread is speculation and references to academic policy. i stand by my referral to the legal forum.

Comment: @preferred_anon -- That's not quite what this says.  The verbatim policy is "Students may not publish, distribute, or sell--electronically or otherwise--any course materials that the instructor has developed in any course of instruction in the University (e.g., presentation slides, lecture aids, video or audio recordings of lectures, and exams) without the explicit permission of the instructor"

Comment: @ScottSeidman I could understand that policy (particularly "sell") if it was intended for distribution outside the university. But it sounds like it applies e.g. to students giving providing notes from previous courses to other students, which would be an unethical restriction. It also seems totally unrelated to academic honesty.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov It might, but enforcement of those rights might still be unethical. Many papers are available online, but rarely with licensing information. Distribution is (strictly speaking) infringement, but lots of people do it anyway, and it doesn't make them academically dishonest.

Comment: @preferred_anon -- they're perfectly free to share *their own* artifacts.  They are not free to share mine.  I simply disagree about this not being related to academic honesty.

Comment: There are cultural differences, obviously, but I'm seeing similar statements in the policies of quite a few Unis, and can't believe it popped up in ours without appropriate benchmarking exercises.

Comment: From uga: "Stealing any information related to academic work (such as past exams, grade records, forms used in grading, books, papers, computer equipment and data, or laboratory equipment and data)."; from cmu: "Supplying or communicating unauthorized information or materials, including graded work and answer keys from previous course offerings, in any way to another student."  I could certainly go on.

Comment: @preferred_anon if you have to quickly jump between "what's legal" and "what's ethical" to maintain your argument, it often indicates a weakness of your position.

Comment: @ScottSeidman You probably could - and I'm taking us off topic so we should probably agree to disagree. But I disagree strongly: the whole point of education is to share knowledge, and a policy that forbids that seems unethical. Nobody objects to free access of their research papers (I hope?) and I don't see how teaching materials are any different. The regulation sounds like it's to do with cheating, but merely sharing resources does not imply that.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov That doesn't make any sense. The legal question is clear - I just think the law is wrong (or, rather, that the law fails to protect things that I would like to happen).

Answer (score 8):

- The legality of "creating a database" differ from country to country, and without knowing the details it is impossible to give an exact answer to your question.
- It may also depend on the purpose. Keeping info for personal use is probably fine; sharing it with others may violate the copyright.
- Your University may have its own rules on what is permitted for you as a student. For example, you may be granted free unrestricted access to a book, software license or electronic service, but you lose these rights when you complete your course and are no longer a student. If in doubt, ask your University first.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with most other answers regarding the copyright issue, I want to give a different perspective on "subverting the educational process" or "academic dishonesty": in my country and field of study, the student government had an offline repository of written accounts of oral exams and written exams. This is in fact one of the primary functions of that institution for most students. Some of the written exams were provided by the instructors, though typically without answers, to the student government. Other written exams would be handed to the students after grading, and the most successful ones were retained in the repository. In some cases, learning from these old exams was about the only way to understand the questions, unfortunately. In all cases, they were valuable tools for checking the study progress and useful practice. Note that all students were well aware of the material, which was provided either free of charge (written exams, you pay only for the copies) or for a "bottle return" fee (oral exam accounts, you get your money back after writing up your own).

Of course, if your institution handles this differently, then things are different. All of this to say: besides the copyright issue, there is also an issue of findability/accessibility. If only some students know about your repository, an unfair advantage may arise.

Comment: Publishing them yourself isn't the same as a governmental repository. The expectations of professors will be different.

Comment: FWIW, as a former student and currently lecturer at a German university (which I assume you refer to) I feel there is a *huge* difference between the Fachschaft ("student association/government") and individuals. The Fachschaft is associated with the university, has an actual policy for handing out materials fairly, and is usually a diverse group of people. In contrast an individual student will leave university sooner or later, may try to act for personal gain or even just get bored, and may be biased against lecturers/lectures. It's much easier to come to an agreement with the former.

Comment: Good to see a matter modeler here!

Answer (score 4):

Although there are already answers that are on the mark, I have to add that, in the United States at least, every fraternity and sorority known to mankind has filing cabinets full of old exams. In fact, it would not surprise me in the least if they haven't scanned at least the newer ones and established a database just such as you are asking about.

What they have not done is *published* that database.  My non-lawyer mind says that scanning might be fair use and so might not be a copyright violation but *publication* of such a database absolutely would be.  Since you've included a "publication" tag on your question, I presume you intend to publish this database, possibly on the Internet.

In that case, the answer to your question is **No, it's not legal,** whether you get  away with it or not.  Someone else owns the copyright on those exams, and you have no right to publish them.  It isn't even necessary to debate who owns that copyright, whether professor, university, book publisher, or someone else.  To address an addition to your question, it also doesn't make any difference that you do not plan to charge for access.  It is the act of *publication* that creates the copyright violation.

I'm retired, but I used to put copyright notices on my exams to try to frustrate outfits like Chegg and Course Hero who collect such material (that they haven't created) and charge for access to it.  It doesn't stop them, but if I win the lottery I'll sue them into oblivion!

Comment: "If I win the lottery I'll sue" is a refreshingly realistic counterpoint to the the typical "It's easy to get rich with a lawsuit" advice encountered from non-lawyers (or unethical lawyers) on the internet.

Comment: Yes, the idea was basically put it in a Google sites. However, then the question arises, can math questions be copyrighted? since indeed all of my courses are math or math based, would changing the numbers then in the questions which could be reduced from "Alice buys apples and she pays 5 dollars for each denoted by the formula 5x" to something like graph 5x would that be a copyright violation? I mean that is just not something you can't copyright or at least I'd hope a math equation cannot be copyrighted, the idea again is to mostly help students for free, not to provide answers like chegg

Comment: @BryanKrause I also observe that buying lottery tickets does not significantly increase one's odds of winning the lottery.  So, Chegg and Course Hero are probably safe from me.  Maybe Elsevier will sue them into oblivion.

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez The web site librarycopyright.net says, "Numbers and basic math problems with only numbers and symbols *probably* aren't protected by copyright. Word problems would be, as would any descriptive text. However, the selection and arrangement of even numerical math problems could be protected by copyright." (Emphasis added.)  As people keep telling you, this might be country-specific, but in general what you propose **would not be legal.**  You mention Google.  I can almost guarantee that someone would send Google a DMCA notice and Google would remove your site.

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely help if you state which country you are in.

As a (former) professor from Canada, yes it is extremely common for professors to re-use exams due to time constraints. In some cases, the professor may have never taught the course before (everyone has a first time) and has no material of their own.

In some universities, **midterms** are often returned to the student and used for study purposes, but publishing the midterm by the student would be a copyright violation of the professors intellectual property. At least in Canada, the professor OWNS the copyright to any material they produce, otherwise free and open research could never happen.

At my institution, **final exams** were never returned.

Unless you're in Germany (apparently), providing a copy of a past test to students currently taking the same course where it is likely known the questions will be re-used, can be seen as the same thing as looking at the exam before hand to know what questions will be on it. That may come down to a personal choice.

For-profit sites that contain previous tests are great for students, and terrible for professors. There are (I believe) professors who seek to  have *their* material taken down from such sites because their permission was not given to publish it there. Is is more of a intellectual property stance and not specifically because they plan on re-using the questions.

If you go ahead and publish it, and you DO get a cease and desist letter from your university, wouldn't you stop publishing it? If so, then nothing else would happen.

Is it legal? Probably.
Should you? Probably not.

Your best course of action would be to simply post questions on the topic that *you* wrote. Then provide the answers if that is what you want to do.

And then you'll find out how hard it is to write different questions every 4 months to check for the same knowledge (varies by discipline of course).

It could also lead to a future money generator for you when you create a course on the topic (that you wrote) like all those bloggers out there. :)

Comment: "At least in Canada, the professor OWNS the copyright to any material they produce, otherwise free and open research could never happen." - what do you mean by this? People share research papers all the time.

Comment: I am in the US in case that changes your response in any way

Comment: @preferred_anon: People share research papers all the time, but without intellectual property people would take credit for other people's work. Research is tied to funding, awards, and prestige, so ownership of research and "discoveries" is very important. To some people anyway.

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez Nope, my answer would still be ask your prof. If I was teaching in the States, I wouldn't want my students studying from things I didn't specifically design to be studied from. If a professor gives back midterms, of course you should study from them, not publish them. The answers are yours to study, the questions are not yours to publish.

Comment: @RickHenderson I don't think that's true. Copyright protects expressions of ideas, not the ideas themselves. If I read your paper, understand your idea & express it in a novel way without crediting you, I have not infringed your copyright (but I have plagiarised). Copyright primarily prevents distributing copies, which for most research is a good thing (maybe for books people disagree, but that's essentially about making money, not plagiarism).

Comment: @preferred_anon  What you describe is fine - learn the material then write a book. What the OP is asking is more like taking the "Reader Exercises" appendix of a text book and publishing that on its own. Yes, it is beneficial to students, no, its not legal

Comment: @MikeB I don't understand your comment. I'm disputing the claim that copyright is a requirement for free and open research. I think I have other comments on this page that express opinions on what the OP is doing (I support it, and I agree it's probably illegal) but they aren't in this thread.